# Upload image and resize with restify

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-uploading, image-resizing, restify

I am using [`restify`](https://github.com/restify/node-restify). On `POST` it gets a JSON object and store the values into database.

Now I need to upload image as well.

**Scenario is:**
Upload image, re-size it to specified sizes(3 types of thumbnails) and save them all on server.

I don't want a complete code. I just need a head start, which `npm` would be best for this scenario?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize image in Node js](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37115815/476716).

Comment: Oh, incidentally my close vote was for Off-Topic (library recommendation), not for duplicate.

Comment: have you implemented upload  using multer .. or something else? can you give some guidance

Comment: @Circle We're using [`gm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm)

Comment: @Shaharyar it is little more to ask ...but can you provide something to get started

Comment: I tried using multer  but in vain https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49832242/multipart-form-data-image-upload-with-restify-and-multer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`multer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) and it's `inMemory` option. Using this you can access the file within a `restify` route handler, manipulate it in memory, and then return it to the client and/or write it to the filesystem after resizing.

There are a bunch of modules on npm that perform image resizing. For example, [`sharp`](https://github.com/lovell/sharp).